git clone --mirror and non-absorbed "here" submodules
Q: in git, is there any way to use "here" submodules, whose original remote repository URLs were specified relatively as INSIDE the repo to which the submodule was added, in a way that is safe with respect to clone --mirror'ing?
Such a tree with nested submodules  seems to be safe with respect to ordinary
clone --recurse-submodules …
But causes problems with
clone --recurse-submodules --mirror … followed by subsequent clones to expand the mirror
Because bare --mirror'ed repositories do not carry the .git/modules directory trees which are essentially local copies of the submodule repo (for disconnected operation(?)).

I am using git version 2.43.0. I am somewhat hopeful that the answer to my question is just "upgrade to a newer version of git".  It is fairly obvious that git submodules are evolving towards maturity, with features such as absorbgitdirs.
---+ A tree with nested submodules
Say that I want to create a tree with nested submodules.
And I create it using "here" submodules - i.e. with relative URLs that are inside the repository
I won't show the details of how one might create such a tree of nested "here" submodules. But it can arise as is described in the git submodule manpage for the absorbgitdirs subcommand:

absorbgitdirs  … A repository that was cloned independently and
later added as a submodule or old setups have the submodules git
directory inside the submodule instead of embedded into the
superprojects git directory.  From
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

But I will show what such a tree may look like
    $>  find lib | grep -v '.git/'
            lib
            lib/.git
            lib/.gitmodules
            lib/file.txt
            lib/m1
            lib/m1/.git
            lib/m1/.gitmodules
            lib/m1/file.txt
            lib/m1/m1.1
            lib/m1/m1.1/.git
            lib/m1/m1.1/file.txt
    OK
    $>  find lib -name '.gitmodules' | xargs head
            ==> lib/.gitmodules <==
            [submodule "m1"]
                    path = m1
                    url = ./m1

            ==> lib/m1/.gitmodules <==
            [submodule "m1.1"]
                    path = m1.1
                    url = ./m1.1
    OK

Ordinary clone works fine:
    $>  git clone --recurse-submodules lib lib.non-mirror
            Cloning into 'lib.non-mirror'...
            done.
            Submodule 'm1' (/home/glew/hack/git-stuff/nested-submodules/test.outer/test.tree/lib/m1) registered for path 'm1'
            Cloning into '/cygdrive/c/Users/glew/Stuff/cygwin.my-stuff/home/glew/hack/git-stuff/nested-submodules/test.outer/test.tree/lib.non-mirror/m1'...
            done.
            Submodule path 'm1': checked out '4a83ba1cdfd73494cfa35754fa65de2a10135e8f'
            Submodule 'm1.1' (/home/glew/hack/git-stuff/nested-submodules/test.outer/test.tree/lib/m1/m1.1) registered for path 'm1/m1.1'
            Cloning into '/cygdrive/c/Users/glew/Stuff/cygwin.my-stuff/home/glew/hack/git-stuff/nested-submodules/test.outer/test.tree/lib.non-mirror/m1/m1.1'...
            done.
            Submodule path 'm1/m1.1': checked out '166b8056d17912ef533ff25c20fb4ec8aa1dd199'
    OK
    $>  find lib.non-mirror | grep -v '.git/'
            lib.non-mirror
            lib.non-mirror/.git
            lib.non-mirror/.gitmodules
            lib.non-mirror/file.txt
            lib.non-mirror/m1
            lib.non-mirror/m1/.git
            lib.non-mirror/m1/.gitmodules
            lib.non-mirror/m1/file.txt
            lib.non-mirror/m1/m1.1
            lib.non-mirror/m1/m1.1/.git
            lib.non-mirror/m1/m1.1/file.txt
    OK
    $> find lib.non-mirror -name '.gitmodules' | xargs head
            ==> lib.non-mirror/.gitmodules <==
            [submodule "m1"]
                    path = m1
                    url = ./m1
            
            ==> lib.non-mirror/m1/.gitmodules <==
            [submodule "m1.1"]
                    path = m1.1
                    url = ./m1.1
    OK

But clone --mirror, and then clone'ing that as non-mirror
FAILs - because the intermediate stage, the mirror, is a bare repository.
It doesn't contain the submodule repo.
     $>  git clone --recurse-submodules --mirror lib.mirror lib.mirror.gen2
             Cloning into bare repository 'lib.mirror.gen2'...
             done.
     OK
     $>  git clone --recurse-submodules lib.mirror lib.mirror.unmirror
             Cloning into 'lib.mirror.unmirror'...
             done.
             Submodule 'm1' (…/lib.mirror/m1) registered for path 'm1'
             fatal: repository '…/lib.mirror/m1' does not exist
             Failed to clone 'm1' …
     BAD=1
     $>  find lib.mirror.unmirror | grep -v '.git/' ; find lib.mirror.unmirror -name '.gitmodules' | xargs head
             lib.mirror.unmirror
             lib.mirror.unmirror/.git
             lib.mirror.unmirror/.gitmodules
             lib.mirror.unmirror/file.txt
             lib.mirror.unmirror/m1
             [submodule "m1"]
                     path = m1
                     url = ./m1
     OK

By comparison, the non-bare repo does contain something that is very much like the submodule and sub-submodule repositories - in the .git/modules directory.    Which, to my eyes, looks very much like a "local copy" of the remote submodules repositories, so you can do disconnected operations.
But the the .git/modules directory is not present in the --mirror bare repo,
it is only present in the non-bare repo:
    $ bash 1293 $>  ddir lib.non-mirror/
    lib.non-mirror/
    |  .gitmodules
    |  file.txt
    +--m1/
    |    .git
    |    .gitmodules
    |    file.txt
    |    +--m1.1/
    |       .git
    |       file.txt
    +--.git/
           HEAD
           config
           index
           +--hooks/
           +--info/
           +--logs/
           +--objects/
           +--refs/
           +--modules/
                  +--m1/
                         HEAD
                         config
                         index
                         +--hooks/
                         +--info/
                         +--logs/
                         +--objects/
                         +--refs/
                         +--modules/
                                +--m1.1/
                                       HEAD
                                       config
                                       index
                                       +--hooks/
                                       +--info/
                                       +--logs/
                                       +--objects/
                                       +--refs/

I guess this makes sense from one point of view.  You can't really do disconnected work using a bare --mirror'ed repo.  You can't really edit files, check them in and out, in the bare --mirror'ed repo.
But… if the --mirror'ed repository is local, or is accessible when other parts of the network, like the remote repositories for the submodules are not accessible, then it most definitely makes sense to be able to clone the bare --mirror'ed repository, get the "local copies" of the submodule repos out, so that you can then do disconnected work.
So, all of this is is just leading up to the question:
Q: is there any way to use "here" submodules, whose original remote repository URL were specified relatively as INSIDE the repo to which the submodule was added, in a way that is safe with respect to clone --mirror'ing?
---+ Why do I care?
Why should I care about this?
It seems to be an artifact, a legacy, as it is described in the git submodule manpage for the absorbgitdirs subcommand:

absorbgitdirs - A repository that was cloned independently and
later added as a submodule or old setups have the submodules git
directory inside the submodule instead of embedded into the
superprojects git directory.  From
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Why not just fix things up via absorbgitdirs and be done with it?
Except… I contend that such nesting of the submodules actually has value.
Without these "here" submodule repos inlined or nested in their parent, you have to have each submodule live "somewhere out there".  Somewhere outside of the context of a libraery within which it is logically nested.
But I won't go into that in any more detail here.
